# installation of matlab using wine

Tags: 12.04, wine, matlab

I have installed WINE and I have .exe file of matlab.When I tried to open setup.exe file of matlab with wine program loader,it does nothing.But I was able to open notepad.exe.
I really want to know what the promblem is and how to debug it

Comment: I know this is not an answer to your question, but... why don't you use the Matlab linux version?. It looks like a more sensible thing to do than run it through Wine.

Comment: Can you run any exe that requires installation?